# How to restrict division in sympy(polynomial)?

Tags: sympy

I have the following expression

```
X=Symbol('X')
expression=(((X**2)*(X-1))*((X*(((2*X)*(X-2))+1))+1)/12)
n,d=fraction(expression)
n=sympify(n).expand(basic=True)
print n/d
```

I am getting following result:

```
X**6/6 -X**5/2 + 5*X**4/12 - X**2/12
```

My expected result is

```
 (2*X**6 - 6*X**5 + 5*X**4 - X**2)/12
```

Is there way in sympy or need to write customize function to handle that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SymPy represents division as [multiplication by power -1](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/manipulation.html). To represent division without evaluation, use [`Mul`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#id33) with setting `evaluate=False`.

```
print Mul(n, Pow(d, -1), evaluate=False)
```

returns

```
(2*X**6 - 6*X**5 + 5*X**4 - X**2)/12
```